# How to get synchonous data in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Is there any way I can make this function synchronous, or add a callback function to run when it's finished?

```
var fbGetLeagues = function(fb) {
  var leagues = [];
  fb.child('leagues').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      var id = child.name();
      var name = child.child('name').val();
      leagues.push({'id': id, 'name': name});
    });
  });
  return leagues;
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Generally, making an async function synchronous is not the answer (but in some cases there are, so I'm curious)

Comment: Actually, I just want to run code when all the leagues are fetched, a callback would be good to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just include a callback & Run if after your `forEach`:

```
var dbGetLeagues = function(fb, callback) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      var id = child.name();
      var name = child.child('name').val();
      leagues.push({'id': id, 'name': name});
    });
    callback(leagues);
}
```

And call the code like:

```
dbGetLeagues(fb, function(leagues) {
    console.log(leagues);
});
```

Comment: But insteam of console.log How do I store in a varible.

Comment: I get value as undefined whenever I try to store  like this `var extvar; dbGetLeagues(fb, function(leagues) {
    console.log(leagues);extvar = leagues
}); console.log(extvar);`