# How to run Firebase and Angualrjs Promises such as $loaded() and then to get values from dependant functions

Tags: angularjs, firebase, javascript

I am building firebase angular app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('appStart',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope,$firebase,,MyFactory){

//this is returning undefined as this point
//How can i pass angualrjs promises so that it returns values once factory finish runnig all operations
    var returnData = MyFactory.getUsersProfile(userId);

});

myApp.factory('MyFactory', ['$firebase', function($firebase){

        var factory = {};

        factory.getUsersProfile = function(userId){

        var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/userprofile").child(userId);
                //retrive the data
                firebaseRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
                    console.log(snapshot.val());
                    var data = snapshot.val();
                    if (data){
 //Here I want to call another function and get and return values once called function finish running
                        var data = factory.getUsersBetsEventsDetails(data); 
                        return data;
                    }else{
                        console.log('return nothing');
                    }
                }, function (errorObject) {
                    console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.code);
                });
            }

            factory.getUsersBetsEventsDetails = function(usersProfileData){
                var firebaseBetsRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/e");
                var userE = [];
                angular.forEach(usersProfileData, function(usersProfileData){
                    console.log('getUsersBets',usersProfileData);
                    var firebaseEData = firebaseBetsRef.child(usersProfileData.e_id);
                    //retrive the data 
                    firebaseE.on('value', function (snapshot) {
                        console.log(snapshot.val());
                        userE.push(snapshot.val());
                        console.log('userE',userE);
                    }, function (errorObject) {
                        console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.code);
                    });
                    //this is the values controller should get 
                    retuen userE;
                }); 
            }

            return factory;
        }]);
```

As I wrote in comments I want run dependent codes after once finish running and not sure how to achieve this?

Anything you not sure in this code? please ask. Thanks

Comment: You're trying to work against the asynchronous nature of Firebase (and every other IO based operation these days). It's simple: you cannot return a value from an asynchronous call, because at the time the `return` statement executes, the server won't have returned a value yet. Instead you have to pass in a callback (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022705/how-to-get-synchonous-data-in-firebase?rq=1) or return a promise (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392166/returning-an-array-using-firebase).

Comment: Thank you Frank Van Puffelen

Comment: @Frank Van Puffelen That raised another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677977/asynchronous-callback-returns-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using callbacks: [How to get synchonous data in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022705/how-to-get-synchonous-data-in-firebase?rq=1)
and http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/