# asynchronous callback returns null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, angularjs-scope, firebase

I am trying to assign callback function values and display `ng-repeat`

```
var myApp = angular.module('mybet',[]);

myApp.controller('MyBetController', function($scope,$firebase,ProfileFactory,MybetFactory){

    $scope.myBetEvents = MybetFactory.getUsersBetsProfile(currentLoggedUser, function(betsData){
        //Callback retuning null value here
        $scope.myBetEvents = betsData;
    });

});

myApp.factory('MybetFactory', ['$firebase', function($firebase){

    var factory = {};

    factory.getUsersBetsProfile = function(userId, callback){

        var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/usersbetsprofile").child(userId);
        var firebaseBetsRef = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com/events");
        var userBettedEvent = [];
        //retrive the data
        firebaseRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            var data = snapshot.val();
            if (data){
                //callback(data);
                angular.forEach(data, function(data){
                    console.log('For Each getUsersBets',data);
                    var firebaseEventsData = firebaseBetsRef.child(data.event_id);
                    //retrive the data of bets
                    firebaseEventsData.on('value', function (snapshot) {    
                        userBettedEvent.push(snapshot.val());
                        console.log('userBettedEvent',userBettedEvent);
                        //if I call callback here then i get the values but calling callback multipul time is no the option 
                }, function (errorObject) {
                    console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.code);
                    });
                });
                //ISSUE:: callback returing null values
                        callback(userBettedEvent);
            }else{
                console.log('Users has no bets');
            }
        }, function (errorObject) {
            console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.code);
            });
    };

    return factory;
}])
```

View::

```
<ul class="list">
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="events in myBetEvents">{{events.event_name}}</li>
 </ul>
```

How can get callback() to return values and display in view? what is causing callback after foreach returning null?

Comment: You are waiting for the first asynchronous call to complete, but you are not waiting for the SECOND asynchronous calls to be complete.

Comment: @epascarello Which line you ref. to?

Comment: look at callback(userBettedEvent); its not inside  firebaseEventsData.on() callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @coder already said in the comments, your `callback(userBettedEvent)` is in the wrong place. Where you have it now, it will be invoked **before** the `on('value'` from Firebase has completed.

From the comments it is clear that you've notice that, yet only want the callback to invoked for one child. You can simply use a `limit` for that.

Something like this would work:

```
if (data){
    data.limit(1).on('value', function(childData) {
        var firebaseEventsData = firebaseBetsRef.child(childData.event_id);
        firebaseEventsData.on('value', function (snapshot) {    
            userBettedEvent.push(snapshot.val());
            callback(userBettedEvent);
        }
    })
```

I haven't really tested the code, but I'm quite sure a `limit` should get you in the right direction.

As a side note: you seem to be using Firebase as a traditional database, pulling the data out like you'd do with SQL. As you may notice: that is not a natural model for Firebase, which was made to synchronize data changes. If you want to stick to pulling the data, you may consider using `once('value'` instead of `on('value'` to ensure the handlers fire only once for every time you try to pull the data from Firebase.