# variable no accessible after a Firebase call

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, scope

I'm using Firebase to access to same data, but i can't use the data out of the function used to access it.
How i can make a console log of the data just accessed instead of the initial value?

```
var whatNeed = 'hello';
gameData = new Firebase('https://thegame.firebaseio.com/gameData');
    gameData.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.val();
        whatNeed = data.property;
    });
console.log(whatNeed);
```

Comment: Call console.log() within the callback, if you can.

Comment: See (a.o) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697907/javascript-assigning-value-to-variable-from-callback-return-timing/25700838#25700838 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677977/asynchronous-callback-returns-null/25684264#25684264 for an explanation of this behavior in the context of Firebase. Since the problem is not specific to Firebase, you can also read these more generic answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/14220323#14220323 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whatNeed` will always contain the initial value when called outside of your callback as the `console.log` will be called first since the `value` event handler is asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the duplicate, i really searched but not found it.